# Oracle SQL - Select only few elements from group

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following table representing tasks in processes:

```
TASK_ID | PROCESS_ID | TASK_TYPE_ID
========+============+=============
1000    | 1          | A
1001    | 1          | B
1002    | 1          | C
1003    | 1          | D
1004    | 2          | A
1005    | 2          | C
1006    | 2          | D
1007    | 3          | A
1008    | 3          | C
1009    | 3          | D
```

I want to isolate different process types. The process type is defined by unique sequence of tasks.

The following query

```
SELECT PROCESS_ID,
       COUNT(*) TASKS_NO,
       LISTAGG(TASK_TYPE_ID,'>') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TASK_ID) TASK_SEQUENCE
FROM mytable
GROUP BY PROCESS_ID
```

can isolate task sequences:

```
PROCESS_ID | TASKS_NO | TASK_SEQUENCE
===========+==========+==============
1          | 4        | A>B>C>D
2          | 3        | A>C>D
3          | 3        | A>C>D
```

Now I want to aggregate it to get this result:

```
TASK_SEQUENCE | TASKS_NO | PROCESS_NO | PROC_REP_IDS
==============+==========+============+=============
A>B>C>D       | 4        | 1          | 1
A>C>D         | 3        | 2          | 2,3
```

PROCESS_NO column should give the number of processes having this same task sequence. Additionally for each distinct tasks sequence (process type) in PROC_REP_IDS column max 3 (representative) PROCESS_IDs should be listed. In my case there could be thousands of processes having the same task sequence, so only three PROCESS_IDs should be listed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [FIRST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641) function with a ordering criteria that places 3 items in first position you should be able achieve your result.

See this sample query where I used WM_CONCAT because LISTAGG is not compatible with FIRST.

```
with mytable as (
        select 1000 TASK_ID, 1 PROCESS_ID, 'A' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1001 TASK_ID, 1 PROCESS_ID, 'B' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1002 TASK_ID, 1 PROCESS_ID, 'C' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1003 TASK_ID, 1 PROCESS_ID, 'D' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1004 TASK_ID, 2 PROCESS_ID, 'A' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1005 TASK_ID, 2 PROCESS_ID, 'C' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1006 TASK_ID, 2 PROCESS_ID, 'D' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1007 TASK_ID, 3 PROCESS_ID, 'A' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1008 TASK_ID, 3 PROCESS_ID, 'C' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1009 TASK_ID, 3 PROCESS_ID, 'D' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual

        union all
        select 1010 TASK_ID, 4 PROCESS_ID, 'A' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1011 TASK_ID, 4 PROCESS_ID, 'C' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1012 TASK_ID, 4 PROCESS_ID, 'D' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual

        union all
        select 1013 TASK_ID, 5 PROCESS_ID, 'A' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1014 TASK_ID, 5 PROCESS_ID, 'C' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1015 TASK_ID, 5 PROCESS_ID, 'D' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual


        union all
        select 1016 TASK_ID, 6 PROCESS_ID, 'A' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1017 TASK_ID, 6 PROCESS_ID, 'C' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual
        union all
        select 1018 TASK_ID, 6 PROCESS_ID, 'D' as TASK_TYPE_ID
        from dual

    )
SELECT TASK_SEQUENCE, MAX(TASKS_NO) as TASKS_NO, COUNT(*) as PROCESS_NO,
    LISTAGG(PROCESS_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PROCESS_ID) as PROC_REP_IDS,
    to_char(wm_concat(PROCESS_ID) keep (dense_rank first order by trunc((seqnum-1)/3))) as PROC_REP_IDS_limited
FROM (
        SELECT p.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TASK_SEQUENCE ORDER BY PROCESS_ID) as seqnum
        FROM (
                SELECT PROCESS_ID,
                    COUNT(*) TASKS_NO,
                    LISTAGG(TASK_TYPE_ID, '>') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TASK_ID) as TASK_SEQUENCE
                FROM mytable
                GROUP BY PROCESS_ID
            ) p
    ) p
GROUP BY TASK_SEQUENCE
```

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro, your query correctly counts the processes having the same task sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Use your query as a subquery and re-aggregate:

```
SELECT TASK_SEQUENCE, MAX(TASKS_NO) as TASKS_NO, SUM(TASKS_NO) as PROCESS_NO,
       LISTAGG(PROCESS_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PROCESS_ID) as PROC_REP_IDS
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TASK_SEQUENCE ORDER BY PROCESS_ID) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT PROCESS_ID,
                   COUNT(*) as TASKS_NO,
                   LISTAGG(TASK_TYPE_ID, '>') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TASK_ID) as TASK_SEQUENCE
            FROM mytable
            GROUP BY PROCESS_ID
           ) p
     ) p
WHERE seqnum <= 3
GROUP BY TASK_SEQUENCE;
```

Comment: Additional problem here is that LISTAGG function can result with too long string (too many IDs listed in a row) while aggregating and Oracle can throw an error. How that could be avoided?

Comment: Sorry @Gordong I had to (temporarly) withdraw my acceptance of your answer. It does not correctly count number of processes having the same task sequence (PROCESS_NO column). This column should show how many processes have this same sequence, now it show always 3.

Comment: @sbrbot . . . That just requires using `SUM()` in the outer query.

Comment: No, that's not correct. PROCESS_NO should represent the number of processes having this particuar task sequence. SUM of tasks is not that.

Comment: @sbrbot . . . It is the sum of the count . . . which is the total count.